# In Rails how can I handle both Ajax request and normal HTML request in same action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My websites has a tabbed format where I populate only 2 out of 5 tabs in users home page. The rest of the tabs are populated with Ajax GET request when user clicks on the tab.
Suppose I have an action to populate the album tab using Ajax upon tab click

```
def show_album
    #code to retrieve album
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :file => "path_offile.js.erb"}
    end
end
```

Inside the js file I use a jquery selector to show a partial in the empty tab-content space.

```
$('#albumtab').html("<%= j (render  :partial => 'profiles/show_my_album' )  %>");
```

The problem is when I want to change the URL using `history.pushState` to "/show_album" so that when people reload the page they would stay on the album tab(sort of how it works on facebook).

So when users reload the page, they come to the same action, but I cannot return a js.erb file from here as there is no existing page where I can add a partial.

So what and how should I return from this action so that users can see the album page. Will I need to create a separate action for normal http requests?

Comment: You could store the state in a cookie.  On refresh, if the cookie says you're in the state you're describing, you could kick off the js to refill the partial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I dont want to use cookies for this. The url "domain/show_albums" should be self sufficient to fetch my album irrespective of browser.

Comment: Then that controller action at that endpoint could kick off the process of loading a different template that loads the partial you need immediately.  You could have `show_albums.erb`  which essentially shows the same thing as your index, except you load the partial you want.  You would probably want to clean up any duplication that creates.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is how do I know if it is an Ajax request in which case I should send a js file, or is it an normal http  call in which case I should render a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def show_album
    #code to retrieve album
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :file => "path_offile.js.erb"}
        format.html{ <whatever stuff you want to happen here>}
    end
end
```

Comment: I was doing this, but I had .html before .js and it was going to html for both normal and ajax requests. Wonder why that was..?